# Does EMF radiation, higher than safety limits suggest, cause cancer?

Tags: cancer, radiation, bioelectromagnetics

Does EMF(radio and microwave spectrum) radiation cause cancer, and what are the safety limits that WHO or independent scientists suggest?

I read this article below; is this true?

[Most cancer in firefighters is due to radio-frequency radiation exposure not inhaled carcinogens](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/19464814/)

Comment: Please don't answer in comments.

Comment: Incidentally, that article you cited is only an hypothesis, so there is no true or false to it. The author is just suggesting it may be a promising avenue of research. Personally, I'm extremely skeptical. There are many professions that spend far more time around radio transmitters than firefighters.